# SSL Support for Communication Between Geth Nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, cpp-ethereum

We are using private Ethereum network for a multi entity use-case. The problem is that all these entities geth nodes sits behind a firewall which only allows TLS traffic.

The node that's broadcasting transactions has to use TLS otherwise the firewalls are blocking the packets. The receiving node's firewall acts as a reverse proxy therefore it doesn't need to have SSL. But how do I make geth use TLS while broadcasting transactions.

Is there a way in ubuntu which will automatically encrypt the unencrypted connections or any sort of proxy based solution?

Comment: Isn't node to node communication already encrypted? If I call ``openssl s_client -connect HOST:30303``, it shows me a valid SSL handshake with TLSv1.2 as protocol.